# 2021 Potential Moderator Election: Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election

**English**

It's time for us to consider holding an election for moderators for Portuguese.SE.

We haven't had one of these before here: all moderators have been appointed
by Stack Exchange. Right now we have only two moderators. Instead of
appointing a new moderator, we would like to hold a community election to
get ourselves back up to the standard three moderators.

To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due
to an insufficient number of candidates, though, we're posting this to try
to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate
themselves once the actual election's nomination period starts. We need
several people running to hold a moderator election.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position,
if we decide to run an election.

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse
check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up.

---

**Português**

Está na hora de considerarmos a realização de uma eleição de moderadores para o Portuguese.SE.

Ainda não tivemos uma eleição dessas aqui: todos os moderadores foram nomeados
pela Stack Exchange. Neste momento, temos apenas dois moderadores. Em vez de
nomear um novo moderador, gostaríamos de realizar uma eleição para
voltar ao padrão de três moderadores.

Para evitar que uma eleição falhe devido a um número insuficiente de candidatos,
estamos a tentar avaliar a disposição dos membros da comunidade de se apresentarem
e nomearem assim que o período de nomeação da eleição real começar.
Precisamos que várias pessoas se candidatem a uma eleição de moderador.

Por favor, deixe uma resposta se gostaria de candidatar-se a uma posição de moderador, se decidirmos realizar uma eleição.

NOTA: Este não é um tópico oficial de nomeação eleitoral, é apenas
para ter uma noção de quantas pessoas estariam dispostas a candidatar-se.

Comment: So there was no interest?

Comment: Can someone PLEASE explain HOW TO VOTE? Esse site inteirinho é bem bagunçado. Quero dizer SE inteiro. TUDO é complicada e nada é óbvio. Credo, me dar dor de cabeça.

Comment: @Lambie [na página da eleição](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) do lado direito em cima tem uma janela pequena com o título "Your ballot". Nessa janela (tem as instruções incluídas) é arrastar e largar (drag&drop) os ícons dos candidatos pela ordem em que quiser votar neles.

Comment: @bad_coder EU SEI. J