# Announcing a Pro Tempore election for 2021

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Portuguese Language Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **June 28** to bring in one more moderator. Despite the lack of interaction on [the interest check post](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/354/15), I checked with the current moderation team and we decided to go ahead with an election anyway.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on June 28, users can [nominate themselves](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On July 5, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still less than two candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on July 13 (or July 20, if we need to extend the nomination period).

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: jNat, there is a [thread running on the pro-tempore election](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/election#comment20032_8785) about the length of the mod term. Is it an already fixed term? Until graduation? Until voluntarily step-down? Could you please answer?

Comment: Responded in the election thread, @gmauch